# Which is better, removing unused styling classes from css library or use a CDN?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Where possible in web app design I have used a CDN to distribute commonly used library's (IE. JQuery, Bootstrap.css etc).

However....

Whilst optimising my latest project I have noticed that the majority of the pages use less than 10% of the bootstrap css, leaving 90% unused.

Edit: This question is about final deployment not development.

Question:

<s>Is it better to use a CDN where there is a very good chance the file has already been cached somewhere local and very probably by the visitors service provider?</s>

Or:

Write your own css file that only uses what you need, dramatically reducing file size and host it locally?

The Bootstrap css minified file is 122kB give or take. In my example 109kB is unused leaving me 13kB of used css file. In this scenario would it be better to host the 13kB locally or the 122kB from a CDN?

Thanks in advance,

Gavin.

Comment: A CDN will provide many more benefits than simply slimming your resources. It's hard to make any general statements about using either.

Comment: How much (in terms of data volume) is “90% of Bootstrap’s CSS” anyway – after minification and Gzipping? (And do you have bootstrap [customized to your needs](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/), so that it only includes the components you are making use of to begin with?)

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or invites discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow

Answer (score 4):

I think it depends on your end user. If you are targeting average users, you can safely assume they have cached CDN resources. You need to analyze your user base.

I always bundle them all and place them on a CDN. Bundling decreases page weight and also benefits your server by offloading work. But it also depends on availability of build process and its automation.

You may find following tools handy.

- Remove unused styles from CSS: https://github.com/giakki/uncss
- Remove unreachable code from javascript: https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS

Comment: if your project is running on server then use CDN 
Google CDN
https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/
MaxCDN
https://www.maxcdn.com/

if you are using in development phase then the project is not connected with Internet , This time you should be use local JS

Comment: I understand your comment about the development stage Smoke, but the question was final deployment. I should of added that in! Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

if your project is running on server then use CDN

Google CDN

[Google CDN](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/)

MaxCDN

[MAX CDN](https://www.maxcdn.com/)

If you are using in development phase then the project is not connected with Internet , This time you should be use local JS and CSS

The main logic behind the all process is the cookie  the **cookie** store CDN path library which is used by another sites and it will **speedup** your site as well.